# Custom annotation used with @RequestMapping is not working in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created custom annotation like this

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
@RequestMapping(consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @interface JsonPostMapping {
    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "method")
    RequestMethod[] method() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "params")
    String[] params() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "headers")
    String[] headers() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "consumes")
    String[] consumes() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "produces")
    String[] produces() default {};
}
```

I have the following controller

```java
import com.config.requestmappings.JsonPostMapping;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @JsonPostMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hi, how are you";
    }

}
```

The `hello` api is also being called with GET request, i am expecting that it should only be called upon POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the alias for `method` in the annotation and use `@PostMapping` instead of `@RequestMapping`. Set the defaults in the body of the annotation itself.

```java
@PostMapping
public @interface JsonPostMapping {
    // ...
    @AliasFor(annotation = PostMapping.class)
    String[] consumes() default { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE };

    @AliasFor(annotation = PostMapping.class)
    String[] produces() default { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE };
}
```